# Nav Bar Only Displaying On First Page iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm developing an app that uses both a Tab Bar and a Nav Bar. Right now, both of these display on the first page that loads for the app, but only the Tab Bar displays when I navigate to different tabs.

My issue is that I'm not entirely sure where the Nav Bar is actually being told to display. I saw posts about having to tie your nav bar and tab bar together, but I didn't fully understand them, and trying to implement them caused my app to not load at all. Should I be instantiating the Nav Bar in each view controller?

This is my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Initialize the window
    window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    // Set Background Color of window
    window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Make the window visible
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // Create TabBarController
    let tabBarController = CustomTabBarController()
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController

    return true
}
```

This is my CustomTabBarController.swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // color TabBar correctly
    let darkTeal = UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.62, blue:0.56, alpha:1.0)
    let lightTeal = UIColor(red:0.6, green:0.78, blue:0.74, alpha:1.0)
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = darkTeal
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:.Normal)

    // customize TabBarItem width
    let tabBarItemWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / CGFloat(4)
    UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage =
        UIImage().makeImageWithColorAndSize(lightTeal, size: CGSize(width: tabBarItemWidth, height: 49.0))

    // create Tab Bar items
    let findOutVC = FindOut()
    let goOutVC = GoOut()
    let speakOutVC = SpeakOut()
    let reachOutVC = ReachOut()

    // images
    let findout = UIImage(named: "find_out")
    let goout = UIImage(named: "go_out")
    let speakout = UIImage(named: "speak_out")
    let reachout = UIImage(named: "reach_out")

    // modify tabBar items
    findOutVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Find Out",
        image: findout,
        tag: 1)
    goOutVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Go Out",
        image: goout,
        tag: 2)
    speakOutVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Speak Out",
        image: speakout,
        tag: 3)
    reachOutVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Reach Out",
        image: reachout,
        tag: 4)

    // set up tabBar items
    let tabs = [findOutVC, goOutVC, speakOutVC, reachOutVC]
    self.viewControllers = tabs

}
```

And this is my CustomNavBarController.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44))

    // change color of nav bar
    let lightTeal = UIColor(red:0.6, green:0.78, blue:0.74, alpha:1.0)
    navigationBar.barTintColor = lightTeal
    navigationBar.translucent = true
    navigationBar.delegate = self

    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "shOUT"

    // left button
    let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Info", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "openInfo")
    let info = UIImage(named: "info")
    leftButton.image = info
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton

    // right button
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Pencil", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "openWrite")
    let pencil = UIImage(named: "pencil")
    rightButton.image = pencil
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

    navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black

    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting frame of UINavigationBar? Is CustomNavBarController is child of UINavigationcontroller?

Comment: Yes it is, should it not be?

Comment: There is no need to set the frame for tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to embed a `NavigationController` inside the `TabBarController`. Specifically, you should insert one `NavigationController` for each tab that you have in your `TabBarController`.
In this way your `NavigationBar` will always be visible during your navigation inside the tabs and the `TabBar` as well.

Here is an image of how your storyboard should look like:

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how to do that programmatically?

Comment: Not really.. The storyboard is a very powerful tool, even if sometimes it turns a bit messy. It allows you to avoid handle lot of stuff that most of the time you forget about.. I suggest to use it ;)